# Reverse Find Return -1 Despite that the Content "End of Project Gutenberg's Crime" is in the text

Tags: python

I was practicing the problem "https://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html". I was doing the part that relates to finding the beginning and the end of the content of an electronic book. 
Here is my python code:

```
from __future__ import division  # Python 2 users only
import nltk, re, pprint
from nltk import word_tokenize
from urllib import request
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('stopwords')
url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554-0.txt"
response = request.urlopen(url)
raw = response.read().decode('utf8')
print(raw.rfind("End of Project Gutenberg's Crime")).
```

The output is `-1`.

But by inspecting the text file on Gutenberg, I find that it has the text "End of Project Gutenberg's Crime". Can anyone explain why it happens to be "-1" as output?

Comment: It doesn't appear quite as you have it. In the book it uses a fancy quote (`’`), not a normal quote (`'`). Change the search string to `"End of Project Gutenberg’s Crime"`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I will try that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It works. Thank you.

Comment: Good. Just a tip, I found that it was a weird quote using the `ord` function to see the code associated with it. `ord("’") => 8217` vs `ord("'") => 39`